# Pivot in SQLite (convert columns to rows)

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to know how can I make a pivot in SQLite. I Have a table with this structure:

```
IDUR IDPIX

2345  4567

2345  4568

2345 4569
```

I need to get this:

```
IDUR IDPIX1 IDPIX2 IDPIX3

2345  4567   4568   4569
```

How to get so, using SQLite?

Answer (score 0):

SQLite doesn't support `row_number()` (or anything similar), so pivoting this is challenging.  Perhaps `group_concat()` is sufficient:

```
select idur, group_concat(IDPIX) as IXPIXes
from t
group by idur;
```

This is easy.  But it does not produce exactly what you are asking for.

EDIT:

In Postgres, you would use conditional aggregation or `crosstab()`:

```
select idur,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then IDPIX end) as IDPIX_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then IDPIX end) as IDPIX_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then IDPIX end) as IDPIX_3
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by idur order by NULL) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by idur;
```

In MySQL, the easiest way uses variables.

Comment: Values into fields are not row number, 2345, 4567, 4568 and 4569 are content string values in each field. Thanks a lot, by your answer.

Comment: Do you know how to get done it, using another tool like mysql or postgresql??

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread so maybe SQLite didn't have row_number back then, but it does have row_number now so this could be easily done today.

So, assuming you know the number of rows you need to turn into columns (in your example, 3) you can solve your problem this way:

### ADD A LITTLE MORE DATA

I wanted to add a little more data so you could see two separate IDUR values turned from rows into columns

| IDUR | IDPIX |
| --- | --- |
| 2345 | 4567 |
| 2345 | 4568 |
| 2345 | 4569 |
| 2346 | 4570 |
| 2346 | 4571 |
| 2346 | 4572 |

### USING LEAD

Here we're using `LEAD` to get the IDPIX of the current row, next row and 2-rows down. (technically, we don't need the `LEAD(IDPIX,0...` and we could just get IDPIX, but it makes it easy to read and see them side-by-side in a uniform format).

```sql
WITH
    CTE AS (
        SELECT
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY IDUR ORDER BY IDPIX) AS ROW_RANKING,
            IDUR,
            LEAD(IDPIX,0,NULL) OVER(PARTITION BY IDUR ORDER BY IDPIX) AS IDPIX1,
            LEAD(IDPIX,1,NULL) OVER(PARTITION BY IDUR ORDER BY IDPIX) AS IDPIX2,
            LEAD(IDPIX,2,NULL) OVER(PARTITION BY IDUR ORDER BY IDPIX) AS IDPIX3
        FROM
            @tbl
    )
SELECT
    IDUR,
    IDPIX1,
    IDPIX2,
    IDPIX3
FROM
    CTE
WHERE
    ROW_RANKING = 1
```

### OUTPUT

| IDUR | IDPIX1 | IDPIX2 | IDPIX3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2345 | 4567 | 4568 | 4569 |
| 2346 | 4570 | 4571 | 4572 |

Comment: DOH, no kidding.  I reflexively typed recursive as I was just earlier doing recursive stuff.  Thanks for the correction @forpas, I'll fix that.